# Capture lines from several files

Tags: shell

There are 5 text files in a folder. Need to capture  from 3rd line to last line from all 5 text files and concatenate them in  a single file using shell script.

Need code for this.

Comment: Hello. Please [edit] your question to **include what you've tried so far**. While you're there please provide an example (source files and expected result).

Comment: Please show some code, which you have already developed, so we can help you on that.

Answer (score 1):

That is easily done with `sed`:

```
sed -s '3,$ !d' *.txt > result.txt
```

`3,$`is an address: from line 3 to the end

`!d` says 'do not delete'

Have a look at http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt for a host of useful sed-oneliners to keep in your shell-scripting toolkit :-)

Comment: I think you need option [`-s` / `--separate`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002dE) (a GNU extension), otherwise the address range is only applied to the first file.

Comment: @Freddy you're right, i forgot!

Comment: Thanks. For the help.